# How to integrate Google Maps in a web application?

Tags: web-applications, google-maps, integration

I have a web application. I want to integrate the Google Maps to show the map of a location where user types in the search location. Any help?

Comment: to show location of your company??

Comment: Not exactly. That location is something of which user is willing to see through the maps. I don't want to disclose further details as it is confidential.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want your users to search for a location, and then display it on the map. If this is the case, that can be done very easily, using the [Geocoding Services](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding) provided by the [Google Maps JavaScript API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/). Consider the following example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Google Maps Geocoding Demo</title> 
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
           type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
   <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 

   var address = 'London, UK';

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
       zoom: 6
   });

   var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

   geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address
   }, 
   function(results, status) {
      if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         new google.maps.Marker({
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            map: map
         });
         map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      }
      else {
         // Google couldn't geocode this request. Handle appropriately.
      }
   });

   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Screenshot:

[image: Google Maps v3 Geocoding Demo]

You can simply substitute the value of the `address` variable, which in this example is set to `'London, UK'` to the location searched by your users.

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1: Open the map you want to embed. It could be a map you created under my maps tab, or a search for address, local business or driving directions.

STEP 2: Copy the HTML code from the textbox after clicking "Link to this page". You can also customize the size of the map and preview it before embedding.

STEP 3 : Paste the HTML code into your website or your blog editor.

or else See this site
http://www.higheredblogcon.com/library/deweese/presentation.html

Answer (score 0):

what you need is

geocoding (a way to turn an address to a long,lat)
http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#geocoding_simple

and a simple map
http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#map_simple